# Error Saving Form Data to Google Spreadsheets Using PHP and the Google Docs API

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I need to post the results from an html form/survey to a google docs spreadsheet. Right now I'm trying the simplest scenario with the api, which is just writing a simple row to my spreadsheet, although I keep getting an error. 
(I'm not too great with php, so please bear with me!)

Code:

```
<?php
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . "$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/ZendGdata-1.12.1/library"); 
require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Query');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$user = "######";
$pass = "######";
$service = "xapi"; 

$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service, null, Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::DEFAULT_SOURCE, null, null, Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::CLIENTLOGIN_URI, 'GOOGLE');

$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);

$feed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheetFeed();

foreach ($feed as $entry) {
echo 'Title: ' . $entry->title . ' - ';
echo 'Id: ' . $entry->id . '<br />';
}
$rowData = array('wood' => 'oak');

$spreadsheetKey = '######';
$worksheetId = 'od6';

try{
$insertedListEntry = $spreadsheetService->insertRow($rowData,
                                                    $spreadsheetKey,
                                                    $worksheetId);
}
catch(Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $exception) {  
    echo "Error: " . $exception->getResponse()->getRawBody();  
} 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with
> message 'Expected response code 200, got 401 <HTML> <HEAD>
> <TITLE>Token invalid</TITLE> </HEAD> <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF"
> TEXT="#000000"> <H1>Token invalid</H1> <H2>Error 401</H2> </BODY>
> </HTML> ' in
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php:714 Stack
> trace: #0
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata.php(219):
> Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'https://spreads...', Array,
> NULL, NULL, NULL) #1
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php(880):
> Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'https://spreads...', Array) #2
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php(768):
> Zend_Gdata_App->get('https://spreads...', NULL) #3
> C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php(210):
> Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('https://spreads...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...',
> NULL) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata.php(162):
> Zend_Gdata_App->getFeed('https://spreads...', 'Zend_Gdata_Spre...') #5
> C:\xa in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php
> on line 714
```

Any help is appreciated! :]

Comment: Too bad you couldn't have used Google Doc forms to save yourself the headache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've worked with this, but I believe the specific error message you're seeing has to do with the service name you're using. `'xapi'` is a generic service name for Google services, but you're trying to access Google Spreadsheets specifically.

Try changing:

```
$service = 'xapi';
```

To:

```
$service = 'wise';
```

Since `'wise'` is the correct [ClientLogin service name](https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#clientlogin) for Google spreadsheets.

Comment: That actually got rid of my error! But I'm getting this now: `"Title: My Spreadsheet - Id: spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/xxxxxxxxxxApgZPKzA Error: We're sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet."`  any idea what this is?

Comment: Sometimes that can genuinely be an intermittant server error on Google's end -- poking around in Google Groups shows a lot of people complaining about this error only to come back and say that the problem went away on its own without them changing their code. I know that you can also see that error if the column names in your script differ in any way from the actual column names on the spreadsheet. But unfortunately this is getting into more unfamiliar territory for me, so hopefully someone more familiar with the API can be more helpful from here on out. :)

Comment: Thank you! I actually just didn't realize that I had to add a column name in the actual spreadsheet first as a "label".  I added a name to A1 and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message refers to an invalid token which means that Google is not accepting your login.  I think the error is in the `$service` line.  Try this:

```
$user = //user name @ gmail here
$pass = //password here
$sheet = //spreadsheet id/key here
$worksheet = "od6";

require_once('Zend/Loader.php');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets');
Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');

$service = Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;
$client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $service);
$spreadsheetService = new Zend_Gdata_Spreadsheets($client);
```

Then all you have to do is this:

```
$rowData = array("column1"=>"blah", "column2"=>"blah"); //replace column1 and column2 with your actual column names and replace blah with the information you want to add
$insertedListEntry = $spreadsheetService->insertRow($rowData,
                                                    $spreadsheetKey,
                                                    $worksheetId);
```

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting an error still. "Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' with message 'Expected response code 200, got 400 We&#39;re sorry, a server error occurred. Please wait a bit and try reloading your spreadsheet.' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ZendGdata-1.12.1\library\Zend\Gdata\App.php:714......."